# tweenlite not working with bitmaps?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following problem when I try to use TweenLite with a Bitmap:

I get strange error messages when applying TweenLite to a Bitmap (tempScore.bitmap). GetBounds works. The bitmap has transparency. Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work? Any help appreciated. Thanks.:)

When using a getBounds-Method I get this:

```
tempScore.bitmap.getBounds(this)(x=2.35, y=-0.45, w=25, h=18)
```

This is the error message:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at com.greensock.plugins::TransformAroundPointPlugin/onInitTween()
at com.greensock.plugins::TransformAroundCenterPlugin/onInitTween()
at com.greensock::TweenLite/init()
at com.greensock::TweenLite/renderTime()
at com.greensock.core::SimpleTimeline/renderTime()
at com.greensock::TweenLite$/updateAll()
```

My imported and activated libraries look like this:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.TransformAroundCenterPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.TransformAroundPointPlugin;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.AutoAlphaPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.ColorTransformPlugin;
import com.greensock.plugins.ColorMatrixFilterPlugin;

TweenPlugin.activate([TransformAroundCenterPlugin, TransformAroundPointPlugin, ColorTransformPlugin,
ColorMatrixFilterPlugin]);
```

This is the part where I try to use TweenLite on my tempScore:

```
var scoreTextLength:int = scoreManager.scores.length - 1;
        for (var counter:int = scoreTextLength; counter >= 0; counter--)
        {

                tempScore = scoreManager.scores[counter];
                tempScore.startDelay = true;

                TweenLite.to(tempScore.bitmap, 2, {transformAroundCenter: {scale:2}});
                trace("tempScore.bitmap.getBounds(this)" + tempScore.bitmap.getBounds(this));

                if (tempScore.update())
                {

                    disposeScore(counter);

                }
        }
```

So far as I can see the getBounds-values are ok. My game is based on a gameframework. There's a renderer inside of it.
Call me an idiot if I'm wrong but is it possible that the renderer of the framework and tweenlite are getting in each other's way??

TweenLite has problems with other similar objects like tempAsteroid. A lot of objects are drawn onto a canvas with copyPixels (blitting-method).

tempScore is a Score-object. The Score object is based on a BasicBlitArrayObject. Otherwise this object extends an EventDispatcher. I hope this little info helps.

This is the scoreManager which manages the look and properties of tempScore:

```
package com.cosmicward.src.classes 
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.geom.*;

import com.framework_mod.src.BlitArrayAsset;


public class ScoreManager 
{
    public var scoreBitmapData:BitmapData;
    public var scoreBitmap:Bitmap;

    public var scoreAnimationFrames:Array = [];

    public var scores:Array;
    public var tempScore:Score;     
    private var textfield:TextField = new TextField();
    private var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    private var $textWidth:int;
    private var $textHeight:int;


    private var rec:Rectangle;

    public var scoreCount:int;
    public var scoreCountTwo:int;
    public var scoreCountThree:int;

    private var drawingCanvas:Shape = new Shape();  

    private var point0:Point = new Point(0, 0);


    public function ScoreManager() 
    {

    }


    public function createScoreLook(textWidth:int, textHeight:int, text:String, textFormat:TextFormat):void {


        var tempBlitArrayAsset:BlitArrayAsset = new BlitArrayAsset();


        scoreBitmapData = new BitmapData(textWidth, textHeight, true, 0x00000000);

        var font:ArialBold = new ArialBold();
        textFormat.font = "ArialBold";
        textFormat.font = font.fontName;
        Font.registerFont(ArialBold);

        textfield.embedFonts = true;
        textfield.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
        //textfield.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
        textfield.defaultTextFormat = textFormat;
        textfield.setTextFormat(textFormat);
        textfield.selectable = false;
        textfield.text = text;


        trace("drawingCanvas.height =" + drawingCanvas.height);
        trace("drawingCanvas.width =" + drawingCanvas.width);

        scoreBitmapData.draw(textfield);/



        $textWidth = textWidth;
        $textHeight = textHeight;

        //*** end look

    }



    public function createScores(xPos:Number, yPos:Number, stopAnimation:int = 5,
                                 scoreDelay:int = 10, scoreLife:int = 40):void {

            var tempScore:Score = new Score(5, 1315, 5, 995);

            tempScore.bitmapData = scoreBitmapData;

            scoreBitmap = new Bitmap(tempScore.bitmapData);

            tempScore.bitmap = scoreBitmap;


            tempScore.x = xPos;
            tempScore.y = yPos;

            tempScore.life = scoreLife;
            tempScore.lifeCount = 0;

            tempScore.widthObject = $textWidth;
            tempScore.heightObject = $textHeight;

            tempScore._delay = scoreDelay;
            tempScore.delayCount = 0;

            tempScore.nextX = tempScore.x;
            tempScore.nextY = tempScore.y;

            scores.push(tempScore);
            }
    }
}
```

Here is some code of the BasicBlitArrayObject (tempScore rests upon that (i.e. Score-object):

```
package com.framework_mod.src
{
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.display.Bitmap;

    public class BasicBlitArrayObject extends EventDispatcher{

    public var x:Number = 0;
    public var y:Number = 0;
    public var nextX:Number = 0;
    public var nextY:Number = 0;
    public var dx:Number = 0; 
    public var dy:Number = 0;
    public var frame:int = 0;
    public var bitmapData:BitmapData;
    public var bitmap:Bitmap;
    public var animationList:Array = [];
    public var testList:Array = [];

    public var point:Point = new Point(0, 0);
    public var speed:Number = 0;

    public var xMax:int = 0;
    public var yMax:int = 0;
    public var xMin:int = 0;
    public var yMin:int = 0;

    public var aniType:int = 1;

    public var health:int = 0;
    public var _size:int = 0;
    public var score:int = 0;
    public var _damage:int = 0;
    public var count:int = 0;
    public var bitmapSize:int = 0;
    public var life:int = 0;
    public var lifeCount:int = 0;
    public var startCount:Boolean;
    public var _delay:int = 0;
    public var delayCount:int = 0;
    public var startDelay:Boolean;
    public var _stop:int;
    public var stopAni:Boolean;
    public var stopAniCount:int = 0;
    public var _type:int = 0;
    public var shield:int = 0;
    public var healthPoints:int = 0;
    public var widthObject:int;
    public var heightObject:int;
    public var boost:Number;
    public var boostLfe:int;
    public var weaponLfe:int;
    public var _projXAdjust:Number;
    public var _projYAdjust:Number;
    public var number:int;
    public var _offset:int;
    public var marked:Boolean;
    public var objMove:Boolean;

    public var removeObj:Boolean;
    public var finished:Boolean;



    public function BasicBlitArrayObject(xMin:int, xMax:int, yMin:int, yMax:int) 
    {
        this.xMin = xMin;
        this.xMax = xMax;
        this.yMin = yMin;
        this.yMax = yMax;
        //trace("basicblittarrayobject");
    }



    public function updateFrame(inc:int, aniType:int = 1):void
    {
        frame += inc;
        switch (aniType) {
        case 1: 
                if (frame > animationList.length - 1){
                    frame = 0;
                }
                bitmapData = animationList[frame];                  
                break;


        case 2: 
                if (frame > animationList.length - 1){
                    frame = 0;
                }
                bitmapData = animationList[1][frame];


                break;
        }


    }   



    public function render(canvasBitmapData:BitmapData):void {
        x = nextX;
        y = nextY;
        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;            

        canvasBitmapData.copyPixels(bitmapData, bitmapData.rect, point);
    }


    public function dispose():void {
        bitmapData.dispose();
        bitmapData = null;
        bitmap = null;
        animationList = null;
        point = null;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but is every element in the `scoreManager.scores` array definitely on the display tree?  Have you tried inspecting this in a debugger to see what the null value is?

Comment: what does disposeScore() do? maybe you are deleting something that is still tweening?!

Comment: disposeScore deletes old scores (garbage collection). I will check that with the scores array (display list) but basically it's just for scores that are created and ready for the rendering process.

Comment: I tried my best to recreated something in wonder.fl to test out scenerios, but right now it feels a bit too complex to answer. If the game engine open for other people to use, let us know. Some of the tween plugins that are listed are pay for plugins, so recreating become even harder.

Comment: The game engine I use is: http://www.8bitrocket.com/books/the-essential-guide-to-flash-games/ . You can download the framework and game examples there (included in one file). Try to use TweenLite (any function, e.g. transformplugin, colormatrix, whatever) with a blitted object (called Mines) in chapter 11 (the game is called BlasterMines (chapter 11)). That would be so cool if someone could help me out with this nasty problem.

Comment: I provided a wrong download link. Sorry! My game rests upon this code: http://www.8bitrocket.com/book/ch11_blastermines.zip . There you can try it for yourself whether TweenLite works when applied accordingly. Try to change the size or color of an object called tempMine inside of the class BlasterMines. I doubt that it'll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is simple, but the resolution is not. The objects you are trying to transform are blitted. So they are not added to the stage. So the object's stage property is null. 
I suspect that the TransformAroundPoint plugin is trying to use the object's stage property, and that is throwing a null object error your are seeing. 
To see a simple example of this, make a very simple file.
Create two bitmaps, add one to the stage, and don't add the other. 
Apply the tween to the stage instance, it will work. 
Then apply the tween to the off-stage instance, and you should get the same error you get in the game.

What you will need to do instead is handle the transform yourself. Instead of using TweenLite to rotate around a point, do it yourself. 
Fortunately Stack Overflow already has a great thread on that topic!
[Rotate around a point that is not (0,0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047993/rotate-around-a-point-that-is-not-0-0)

Comment: Greensock (maker of TweenLite) said that it can tween non-Display Objects because it can tween ANY numeric property of ANY object. Some plugins require a display object though so I have to change the plugins if I want to use them. But I tested it with other plugins like colorMatrixFilter and it still doesn't work (this plugin doesn't require a display object). The renderer of the framework copies the bitmapData to the canvas via a copyPixels-method. I think that's the problem why it doesn't work. Pre-rendering scores makes no sense because they are dynamically created.

Comment: TweenLite can indeed tween non-display objects. But the TranformAroundPoint plugin requires a display object. (You can't transform an alpha value around a point, for example)  - and it seems to make some reference to the display objects stage property. Hence the null object error if the display object is not added to the stage. Does that make sense?